# In "Functional Analysis," is the word "Functional" an adjective, or a noun?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

Does 'functional' mean "relating to functions" or "a mapping from a space to its scalars"?

Comment: Well, that's an original question! :-) If it were a noun, though, it would be "analysis of functionals". Thus, I believe it is an adjective.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro There's a reasonable discussion where I'm from about whether the 'central' in 'Central Limit Theorem', refers to 'limit' or to 'theorem', and the translation would change accordingly.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: oh yeah, that's another super-classic fact. Nobody knows why that theorem is called like that.

Comment: See [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html).   I think it is both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering one of the foundational results of functional analysis is the [Banach-Steinhaus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle), I think it's safe to say that functional here means 'relating to functions'.

In practice, however, I'd say a good analogy would be infinite-dimensional linear algebra.
So there should be a caveat about 'relating to *linear* functions', but they need not be functionals (ie, mapping to scalars).